# Clipping WMS layer

Tags: leaflet, wms

I have a WMS layer which I want to be able to clip based on a 256 by 256 px square buffer created by user click.
The buffer is created around the point user clicks on. When I display the WMS layer, I am able to see the layers and everything works fine. When the clipped region is displayed I get this  `Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response` error.
My problem here is why I get this error only when I reset the params for the WMS layer and not when loading the original WMS layer. Is there a workaround? I'm posting the code for better understanding:

```
// Create the map
var map = L.map('map').setView([33.69379712914481, 73.0651823914226], 13);

// Add a base layer
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a> contributors',
}).addTo(map);

// Create a new WMS layer for the complete region
var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Islamabad/wms?', {
    layers: 'Islamabad:Islamabad',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    attribution: ''
}).addTo(map);

// Event listener for map click
map.on('click', function (event) {
    // Remove any previously created point and buffer layer
    if (typeof pointMarker !== 'undefined') {
        map.removeLayer(pointMarker);
    }
    if (typeof bufferLayer !== 'undefined') {
        map.removeLayer(bufferLayer);
    }

    // Create a point at the clicked location
    var point = event.latlng;
    pointMarker = L.marker(point).addTo(map);

    // Calculate the corner coordinates of the buffer square
    var bufferDistance = 128; // Half of the side length of the square buffer in pixels
    var containerPoint = map.latLngToContainerPoint(point);
    var northWest = map.containerPointToLatLng(containerPoint.subtract([bufferDistance, bufferDistance]));
    var southEast = map.containerPointToLatLng(containerPoint.add([bufferDistance, bufferDistance]));
    var bufferBounds = L.latLngBounds(northWest, southEast);

    // Create a rectangle buffer layer
    bufferLayer = L.rectangle(bufferBounds, {
        color: '#ff0000',
        weight: 1,
        fillOpacity: 0.1
    }).addTo(map);
    
    ***wmsLayer.setParams({ bbox: bufferBounds })*** //this is where I get the error. 

    // Zoom to the buffer area
    map.fitBounds(bufferBounds);
});
```

Comment: Putting aside CORB error, I strongly doubt that tile layer can return result exactly for desired bbox. For test try initially request WMS with bbox.